# How to remove “restore defaults” button in custom Preference Page

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Using `noDefaultAndApplyButton()` is removing both the apply and restore default button but i need to remove only restore default button. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Version 3.11 of JFace which is in Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) adds a `noDefaultButton()` method which turns off just the 'restore defaults' button.

On older versions you can call `noDefaultAndApplyButton()` to suppress the default buttons and override the `contributeButtons` method to add your own Apply button - you will have to handle this button yourself.

Something like:

```
  @Override
  protected void contributeButtons(final Composite parent)
  {
    final Button applyButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    applyButton.setText("Apply");

    final int widthHint = convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(IDialogConstants.BUTTON_WIDTH);
    final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false);
    final Point minButtonSize = applyButton.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true);
    data.widthHint = Math.max(widthHint, minButtonSize.x);
    applyButton.setLayoutData(data);

    applyButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
        performApply();
      }
    });

    final GridLayout layout = (GridLayout)parent.getLayout();
    layout.numColumns++;
  }
```

Comment: Can you give me some example as how to add the apply button in contributeButtons

Comment: Updated answer with example code

Comment: Well, I had the same requirement, but I couldn't do the above, so here is what I did.
I overided the function:
@Override
public boolean isValid(){
    getDefaultsButton().setEnabled(false);
    return super.isValid();
}
PS: I couldn't do the above due to other requirements!